# RXTX on Ubuntu 12.04 & Netbeans

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans

Looking to add RXTXcomm.jar (the javax.comm replacement) from http://rxtx.qbang.org/
I can add RXTXcomm.jar to the project library with no problems but I get the error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
>   thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to install librxtx-java package?

```
$ aptitude search rxtx
v   lib-rxtx-java                              -                                                     
v   lib-rxtx-java:i386                         -                                                     
p   librxtx-java                               - Full Java CommAPI implementation                    
p   librxtx-java:i386                          - Full Java CommAPI implementation                    
p   librxtx-java-dbg                           - Full Java CommAPI implementation, Debugging Symbols 
p   librxtx-java-dbg:i386                      - Full Java CommAPI implementation, Debugging Symbols
```

Probably you need this .so files:

```
$ apt-file list librxtx-java | grep jni
librxtx-java: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxI2C-2.2pre1.so
librxtx-java: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxI2C.so
librxtx-java: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxParallel-2.2pre1.so
librxtx-java: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxParallel.so
librxtx-java: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxRS485-2.2pre1.so
librxtx-java: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxRS485.so
librxtx-java: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxRaw-2.2pre1.so
librxtx-java: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxRaw.so
librxtx-java: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so
librxtx-java: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial.so
librxtx-java-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/jni/librxtxI2C-2.2pre1.so
librxtx-java-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/jni/librxtxParallel-2.2pre1.so
librxtx-java-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/jni/librxtxRS485-2.2pre1.so
librxtx-java-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/jni/librxtxRaw-2.2pre1.so
librxtx-java-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so
```

You can install it with:

> $ sudo apt-get install librxtx-java

After that, probably you must add /usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar to your classpath.

```
$ apt-file list librxtx-java | grep jar
librxtx-java: /usr/share/java/RXTXcomm-2.2pre2.jar
librxtx-java: /usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar
```

Here you can find gnu.io.CommPort class

```
$ jar tvf /usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar | grep CommPort
  1453 Fri Nov 11 10:39:50 CET 2011 gnu/io/CommPort.class
   818 Fri Nov 11 10:39:50 CET 2011 gnu/io/CommPortEnumerator.class
  5753 Fri Nov 11 10:39:50 CET 2011 gnu/io/CommPortIdentifier.class
   340 Fri Nov 11 10:39:50 CET 2011 gnu/io/CommPortOwnershipListener.class
```

You can follow [Netbeans documentation](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-configuring) for adding the jar to the classpath.

Hope this will help you

Comment: error: package gnu.io does not exist; import gnu.io.CommPort;

In netbeans is there a setting i should change to make it work?

Comment: After that, probably you must add /usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar to your classpath.

Comment: its 0600 here and I'm beginning to make mistakes. any chance you could list the command for adding it to the class-path permanently?

Comment: RANT: FFS Ubuntu/Java im a dev not a SEtUP Netbeans OSer. I have wasted hours and hours why cant you make this easy even the rxtx site documentation is shit. =( That said. once i get it working i will try to write a guide from all your help Stack/sourcerebels =) referenced ofc

Comment: Tbh this is not going to help. The OS needs to set the classpath right ? OR does the IDE override this ? If so .. RXTX / gnu is not listed in the library. 
 export  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/myuser/javalibs/RXTXcomm.jar is suggested by http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Installation_on_Linux

Comment: ok this seems to work
add jar/folder (Project > Properties > Libraries > Add Jar/Folder) then add the location /usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar

Comment: I get a  
RXTX Version mismatch
Jar version = RXTX-2.2pre2
native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7

Answer (score 1):

Using Netbeans 7.2 on 12.04 all I did was install the package like so: `sudo apt-get install librxtx-java`

Then all that's left to do in the Netbeans project is to add the actual jar file, which lives in `/usr/share/java/rxtxcomm.jar` to the class path by opening the project properties, navigating to **Libraries** and adding the file using the **Add JAR/Folder** Button.

All set.