# How does java determine what native libraries to load?

Tags: java, linux-kernel, rxtx

I'm using RXTXComm.jar in Linux and having issues.  I suspect that it's the native library being used.  I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007861/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-jni-libraries-which-are-loaded) article to help determine what `.so` files are being loaded to help support that library.

My output listed "/usr/lib/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so"

My question is - how that library was dynamically loaded?

A follow up question may be how could I remove "librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so", so that I can load "librxtxSerial.so" instead.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't loaded librxtxSerial.so yet.  I have two libraries for RXTXComm.  RXTXcomm and RXTXcomm-2.2pre2.  I initially used RXTXcomm-2.2pre2 but was not successful when sending bytes to the device I'm working with.  I wanted to try RXTXcomm instead.  Linux offered several .so files when I used. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380526/rxtx-on-ubuntu-12-04-netbeans.  After I changed libraries, the .so file used didn't change.  That lead me to my question.